# Google search dynamically, when we click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

We need to implement a link which will render with some **information** and when we click on the link, it should open Google, with search results for the **information**.

I tried with http://google.com/search?q={information}. I know this is not the right way. Please suggest your thoughts..

"Drive your dream with your passion"
- Praveen V.

Comment: You can begin here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: Can you please provide any sample for it?

Comment: Why isn't that the right way? That is how you open Google with a given query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their might by an API made for that, but the easiest way still is:

https://www.google.be/search?q=hello+world